# Best ASP.NET application Deployment method

Tags: asp.net, deployment

Which is the best method to deploy a web application. Currently i am publishing the application and placing that folder in the server and creating virtual directory and providing windows authentication.

I just want to know this is a better metod to deploy or i need to use any other deployment technique?

Plese suggest

Comment: Plz check this thread, hope this will help you… http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974799/what-method-do-you-use-to-deploy-asp-net-applications-to-the-wild/974876#974876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the situation.  For some situations, using Visual Studio's publish feature (right click project) works great.  However in some situations, particular larger organizations or environments where the infrastructure group and development team are a little more isolated, you need to use a Web Application Installer or an MSI package.  I've also had instances where the easiest thing to do was create a simple .bat file and create an external command in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Use a web application installer, easy to create with Visual Studio.

Comment: Web application installer is it a tool ? Free version ?

Comment: No, it is a Visual Studio feature, another project type. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you need a third person to deploy your application in production servers, I would suggest you to deploy using a MSI, it would also help you to version your release.

MSI can be created using various ways including but not limited to

- Deployment projects in VS studio
- WixGen
- Click once