# How to deploy an asp.net webApp to multiple servers?

Tags: asp.net, deployment

How to deploy an asp.net webApp to multiple servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy Web Applications Using the Copy Web Tool

also check thread

[What method do you use to deploy ASP.Net applications to the wild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974799/what-method-do-you-use-to-deploy-asp-net-applications-to-the-wild/974876#974876)

Answer (score 1):

It depends how many servers you're talking about.

For less than about 4 or 5 servers, I just zip the application, copy to each server, unzip into a new folder, and tell IIS to look at the new folder, using IIS Manager.  In a load-balanced environment, it also means taking all servers except one offline, and then updating them one at a time, and bringing them back online afterwards.

For more servers than that, I prefer to use Windows Deployment Services (WDS).